# Ethersjs: Calling a method in a smart contract: nonce has already been used, Nonce too low

Tags: ethers.js, nonce

I have a contract that has a simple method:

```
function getOwner() external returns (address) {
  return owner;
}
```

I'm trying to call it in `NodeJs` using `ethers` library:

```
// create the provider and the signer
const provider = new ethers.getDefaultProvider("http://127.0.0.1:8545/");
let signer =  new ethers.Wallet('[privatekey]',
    provider );
let manager = new NonceManager(signer);

// create contract
let contractAddress = "[contractaddress]";
let abiString = fs.readFileSync(contractAbiPath).toString();
let abi = JSON.parse(abiString);
let contract = new ethers.Contract(contractAddress, abi, signer);
await contract.waitForDeployment();

// get the current nonce
let walletNonce = await signer.getNonce(); 

// send the transaction

// error1: if I pass walletNonce + 1
let transaction = await contract.getOwner({
    nonce: walletNonce
});
// error2 : if in the line above I passed walletNonce
let response = await manager.sendTransaction(transaction);
await response.wait(1);
```

If `walletNonce` is `6`, and I pass it like this: `nonce: walletNonce`, I get the error at line `let response = await manager.sendTransaction(transaction);`:

```
Nonce too low. Expected nonce to be 7 but got 6
```

However if I pass `nonce: walletNonce + 1`, I get the error at line

```
let transaction = await contract.getOwnerAddress({
    nonce: walletNonce
});
```

```
Nonce too high. Expected nonce to be 6 but got 7. Note that transactions can't be queued when automining.

could not coalesce error
```

I'm lost as to what to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing is really weird. The line `let transaction = await ...` sends correctly a transaction, but to get a response you need to do:

```js
let response = await transaction.wait();
```

In any case, this response will contain the transaction receipt, which won't tell anything about the owner.

If you want to read the owner from the contract, then change the solidity function to `view`:

```
function getOwner() external view returns (address) {
  return owner;
}
```

and do simply `let owner = await contract.getOwner();`

Comment: Thank you, it worked! Do I understand correctly, that the `owner` value returned by the `getOwner` method is not possible to read in my `NodeJs` code? From my research, it appears that only events would be viewable?

Comment: Yes, values returned by a function can be read only if it's "view".